# Perl - how to grep a block of text from a file

Tags: perl, grep

It can be in XML or any text format. How in general to grep for a block of text in Perl?

```
<track type="ws">
      <range>
       <rangeStart>0</rangeStart>
       <rangeEnd>146.912</rangeEnd>
       <locationIndex>0</locationIndex>
       <propertyIndex>0</propertyIndex>
      </range>
</track>
<track type="ps" id="1">
      <range>
       <rangeStart>0</rangeStart>
       <rangeEnd>146.912</rangeEnd>
       <locationIndex>1</locationIndex>
       <propertyIndex>1</propertyIndex>
      </range>
</track>
```

I want to grep for `type="ps"` and get everything till the `</range>`.

One solution is to open the file, read it line by line and then match the block.

```
open(FH, "file.txt");
foreach $line (<FH>) {
    if ($line =~ m/type="cc"(.*?)<\/range>/) {
        print $1;
    }
}
```

but is there a more optimal solution without reading the file line by line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bjørn is absolutely right for XML. For your more general question, you might also be interested in one of my most favorite per one-liners:

```
perl -ne 'print if /type="cc"/../<\/range>/' input.txt
```

Comment: great!! thanks.. i was actuall looking for a more general approach and not an xml specific.. this works.

Answer (score 3):

Reading line by line will only work if the XML is formatted with newlines like this, which it's likely not. You should be using a real XML parser.

If your data isn't too large (a few (tens of) MB) then you might be able to read it with [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm) and then traverse the generated data structure. You should also have a look at [XML::XPathEngine](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-XPathEngine/lib/XML/XPathEngine.pm).

Answer (score 0):

For XML look at [xml_grep](https://metacpan.org/module/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.42/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep) and [xml_grep2](https://metacpan.org/release/App-xml_grep2). XML is quite different from plain text in that it is not line-oriented, so line oriented tools like grep, sed, awk or [ack](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3aAck) are not guaranteed to work properly.